# WEKA on windows 7, command line with few arguments

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, weka

I'm trying to lance a perl script which calls  **weka.classifiers.trees.J48**. I have several global thoughts to ask you and I appreciate your feedbacks.

1-WEKA is written in Java. In order to run weka.jar I need java. It's the same as having HelloWorld.jar

2-I installed Java and added it to Path variable.Weka.jar needs a few arguments. if i write     **java -jar** **"**c:\programs\weka.jar**"** **input1 input2**   is it correct?

3-how about java -jar** **"**c:\programs\weka.jar **input1 input2*** *"** or 
            java ** "c:\programs\weka.jar" **input1 input2**   **-jar**

4-I need the class weka.classifiers.trees.J48 . should i write 
**java -jar** **"**c:\programs\weka.classifiers.trees.J48**"** **input1 input2**  without .jar?

5-someone in stackoverflow suggested to put weka in a **user** environment variable which should be called CLASSPATH. my problem is i'm not sure if i should put WEKA folder in this environment variable (as we always do in path **system** env. variable) or i put **weka.jar** the file and not the folder in the CLASSPATH
So, Assuming that weka.**jar** is now in my classpath,does the command change to 
java -jar weka.classifiers.trees.J48 **input1 input2**

I'm confused, i get Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: weka/classifiers/tree
 s/J48
 I want to know how the **command sequence** works and if it's a **general case**. thanks for any insight

Answer (score 0):

Weka installation provides RunWeka.bat file. You can look its contents for an example. Also a different example I provided below.

To test your weka installation you can use  **weka.core.SystemInfo**. This class does not expect any arguments. You can use this class to see if your command line environment can see weka jar.

wekaTest.cmd

```
SET WEKA_HOME=D:\atilla\tools\Weka-3-7
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASPATH%;%WEKA_HOME%\weka.jar
java weka.core.SystemInfo
```